# Steam webAPI Jquery script. return

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, webapi, steam

I have a problem with this script I got from github.

I added `value.appid` myself because that seemed logical but I believe it data.response.games is a response for all my games and its values.

How do I get them to either print or see what is defined?

I would need something like `value.description` or maybe `value.ownedAchievements`.

I want to see what data i have to work with for the CSV.

I am a complete noob with this so be nice, also too expert comments I will have no clue what to do with cause I have never touched javascript in my life before.

I am currently learning HTML CSS and PHP.

I have a Docker running with my SQL as well... is there also a way to re-engineer this script to directly put these value.* values inside a column? without the need to download a CSV and import it manually all the time.

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    function exportSteamToCSV(filename) {
        var url = "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=" + $('#webkey').val() + "&steamid=" + $('#steamid').val() + "&format=json&include_appinfo=1";
        
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            colDelim = ',';
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"';
            csv = '"Name","Playtime","Store' + rowDelim;
            $.each(data.response.games, function(index, value) {
                url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/" + value.appid;
                csv += value.name + colDelim + value.playtime_forever + colDelim  + value.appid + colDelim + url + rowDelim; 
                //csv += value.name + colDelim + value.playtime_forever + colDelim  + url + rowDelim;   Was correct eerste versie
            });
            csv += '"';
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
              var link = document.createElement("a");
              link.download = filename;
              link.href = csvData;
              link.target = "_blank";
              link.click();

        });
    };
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportSteamToCSV.apply(this, ['steamgames.csv']);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: What does the script do?  Build a CSV file?  Is a _file_ what you really need?  Is speed the problem?  Is the set of values the problem?  Something else?

Comment: no the problem i already figured out the first part with a lot of help, how to see what it actually gets from steam as value.*.. it aint much. 
But i would like to make the process automaticly. 
Each collumn need to fill a table in the Database. 
i have 4 columns per row. 
title, minsPlayed, appID and StoreURL. 
i may beed to add "description"to that as well, but thats another think i am working on now, to grab and process the <Div> content from the store website. 

How do i turn this script into an automated process? when the website (steamgames.php) loads?

Comment: Caution:  a CSV has some kind of delimiter (comma, tab, whatever).  Such characters _may_ exist in the `<div>`, thereby leading to ambiguity in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this later in Laravel with the query from the APU. the URL just gets all the data.. from there you casn pretty much do anything.

```
$url = "https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXX&steamid=XXXXXXXXXXformat=json&include_appinfo=1";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$games = $parsed['response']['games'];
echo SteamGame::count();
foreach($games as $game){
echo $game['name']."<br>";
$imgid = $game['appid'];
SteamGame::updateOrCreate(['name' => $game['name']],[
    'name' => $game['name'],
    'appID' => $game['appid'], 
    'storeURL' => "https://store.steampowered.com/app/".$game['appid'],
    'imageURL' => "https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/${imgid}/header.jpg",
    'minutesplayed' => $game['playtime_forever']
    ]);
```